# Create a dbf table by copying the structure of another dbf table

Tags: arcobjects, vba, database

I have a dbf table and I wish to automatically create another dbf table with a different name but with exactly the same structure i.e.fields as the existing table. Is there any ready code in VBA and ArcObjects for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non ArcObject option within VBA would be to simply use the VB [FileCopy function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

FileCopy "C:\Temp\Join_Output.dbf", "C:\Temp\Join_Output2.dbf"

Comment: Wouldn't this copy the data? I'm not sure Demetris wants to do that (he was unclear, though).

Comment: Might sound long handed, but wouldn't it be better to simply copy the whole data across and then delete it all?

Comment: No, I do not want to copy the data; only the structure i.e. fields. Does the FileCopy function copy the data as well?

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that accessing the [Create Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Create_Table/0017000000n5000000/) tool from `IGeoProcessor2` factory might do exactly what you wish, as Create Table allows for a template table. You can find out more about executing GP tools [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_run_a_geoprocessing_tool/0001000003rr000000/).